# Crystal Reports changing field color using IF statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to change the background color of a row in crystal reports based on comparing two data fields. For example. `If GPA_01 < GPA 02 then the background color should be red. else the background color should be white`. When attempt to create the formula i get an `error message saying the " a number is expected here"` it's highlighting the field after the comparison sign in this case the <.  **I'm thinking the field after the < needs to be converted to a number but I'm not sure how to do that.**

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two fields are numeric, try:

```
If {table.GPA_01} < {table.GPA 02} Then
  crRed
Else
  crNoColor
```

Answer (score 0):

use `CINT()` to convert to integer

```
If CINT({table.GPA_01}) < cINT({table.GPA 02}) Then
  crRed
Else
  crNoColor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If CINT({table.GPA_01}) < cINT({table.GPA 02}) Then
'crRed'
 Else
 'crNoColor'
```